# ASP.NET default credentials for WEB API calls

Tags: asp.net, authentication, dotnet-httpclient, credentials

I have famous problem. My web Asp.net application has Windows Authentication(in IIS). I need this credentials pass to my ERP API which is required "Basic Authentication". Is any way to get these credentials? I have tried `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` and also `HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }` but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not something you can do. Windows Authentication works on a windows account and windows handles it underneath. You won't be able to retrieve password for this account programmatically as that would be a security breach.

Therefore, you have to send the credentials to ERP explicit (as for them in the app after user is authenticated and pass to the API or do research and find other ways to authenticate in ERP API, maybe there is something available).